# Whenver I am passing data from controller to view I am getting error as variable not defined

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

Here is my cotroller code

```
public function registration(){
$this->load->model('user_model');
$result_data['count']=$this->user_model->count_batch_student();
if($_POST){
    $data=array(
        "first_name"=> $this->input->post('fname'),
        "last_name"=> $this->input->post('lname'),
        "dob"=> $this->input->post('dob'),
        "gender"=> $this->input->post('gender'),
        "email"=> $this->input->post('email'),
        "mob"=> $this->input->post('mob'),
        "course"=>$this->input->post('course'),
        "batch"=>$this->input->post('batch'),
        "address"=>$this->input->post('address'),
        "city"=>$this->input->post('city'),
        "state"=>$this->input->post('state'),
        "pin"=>$this->input->post('pin'),
        "address"=>$this->input->post('address'),
        );
    $result_data['user_result']=$this->user_model->register_data($data);
}
$this->load->view('sunnon_registration', $result_data);
}
```

Here is my model code, First I am checking the email id is already exist or not if it is exist I am just updating the table if it is not then I am inserting the data into the table.

```
    public function register_data($data){
        extract($data);
        $query="select * from a3m_account where email='$email'";
        $result=$this->db->query($query);
        if($result->num_rows()>0){
            $query="update a3m_account set first_name='$first_name', last_name='$last_name', dob='$dob',gender='$gender',email='$email',contact_num='$mob', address='$address', city='$city',state='$state', pin='$pin', course='$course', batch='$batch'";
            $this->db->query($query);
            return "User already exist";
        }else{
            $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()_-=+;:,.?";
            $password = substr( str_shuffle( $chars ), 0, 5);
            $query="insert into a3m_account (first_name, last_name, dob, gender,email, contact_num, address, city, state, pin, course, batch, password ) values('$first_name', '$last_name', '$dob', '$gender', '$email', '$mob', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$pin', '$course', '$batch', '$password')";
            $this->db->query($query);
$query="select email, password, id from a3m_account where email='$email'";
                $result= $this->db->query($query);
                if($result->num_rows()> 0){
                    return $result-> result("array");
                }
        }
    }
```

Whenever I am  it gives error as Variable Undefined

Comment: What "variable undefined" error are you gettin?

Comment: Just a suggestion with your password why not use http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and for verify http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: use $result-> result_array(); instead of $result-> result("array");

Comment: Seriously, you expect us to help when you have not given the details about the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below use `$data = array()` in `register_data($data = array())` instead of extract($data);

```
public function register_data($data = array()) {

    $message = array();

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('a3m_account');
    $this->db->where('email', $data['email']);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() >0 ){

        $update_info = array(
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
            'dob' => $data['dob'],
            'gender' => $data['gender'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'contact_num' => $data['mob'],
            'address' => $data['address'],
            'city' => $data['city'],
            'state' => $data['state'],
            'pin' => $data['pin'],
            'course' => $data['course'],
            'batch' => $data['batch']
        );

        $this->db->where('id', $query->row()->id);
        $this->db->update('a3m_account');

        $message = 'User all ready exists';

    }else{ 

        $new_password = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $insert_info = array(
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
            'dob' => $data['dob'],
            'gender' => $data['gender'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'contact_num' => $data['mob'],
            'address' => $data['address'],
            'city' => $data['city'],
            'state' => $data['state'],
            'pin' => $data['pin'],
            'course' => $data['course'],
            'batch' => $data['batch'],
            'password' => $new_password
        );

        $this->db->set($insert_info);
        $this->db->insert('a3m_account');

        $message = 'New User';

    }

    return $message;
}
```

To create password hash. Password column make sure varchar 255

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

On your login function use this below to verify password

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Controller

```
public function registration(){

$created = '';

$this->load->model('user_model');

$result_data['count'] = $this->user_model->count_batch_student();

if($_POST){

    $data = array(
        "first_name"=> $this->input->post('fname'),
        "last_name"=> $this->input->post('lname'),
        "dob"=> $this->input->post('dob'),
        "gender"=> $this->input->post('gender'),
        "email"=> $this->input->post('email'),
        "mob"=> $this->input->post('mob'),
        "course"=>$this->input->post('course'),
        "batch"=>$this->input->post('batch'),
        "address"=>$this->input->post('address'),
        "city"=>$this->input->post('city'),
        "state"=>$this->input->post('state'),
        "pin"=>$this->input->post('pin'),
        "address"=>$this->input->post('address'),
    );

    $created = $this->user_model->register_data($data);

}

$result_data['message'] = $created;

$this->load->view('sunnon_registration', $result_data);

}
```

View

```
<?php echo $message;?>
```